# How do I control the up/down controls to only minutes in C# Windows Forms DateTimePicker?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have a C# Windows Forms control with a DateTimePicker set to only show Time (Custom Format h:mm) and my users will almost always be clicking the up/down buttons to control the minutes.  However, by default the control updates the hours.

How can I make those buttons control the minutes by default?

And as a bonus, is it possible to make the hour roll forward/back when the minute goes past 60?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edper's answer is correct, it will automatically set the datetimepicker to update the minutes once it's got the focus.
However, the hour's part is not automatically forward or rollback when the minute goes past 60.

You need to handle the KeyDown event for that.

Try this (I combined with Edper's answer).

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "h:mm";
       dateTimePicker1.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(dateTimePicker1_MouseWheel);
       dateTimePicker1.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(dateTimePicker1_KeyDown);
       dateTimePicker1.GotFocus += new EventHandler(dateTimePicker1_GotFocus);        
    }

    void dateTimePicker1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("{right}");
    }


    void dateTimePicker1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Delta > 0)
            dateTimePicker1.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddMinutes(1);            
        else
            dateTimePicker1.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddMinutes(-1);            
    }   

    void dateTimePicker1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyValue == 38)
        {                
            dateTimePicker1.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddMinutes(1);
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
        else if (e.KeyValue == 40)
        {
            dateTimePicker1.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddMinutes(-1);
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: As expected, what a perfect answer

Comment: When I try using GotFocus, it looks like I'm already too late and the Hours have already incremented once, then it sends the focus to the right.

Answer (score 1):

When the `datetimePicker` got the `Focus` then you send keys to the right which automatically goes to the minute portion.

```
dateTimePicker1.GotFocus += new EventHandler(dateTimePicker1_GotFocus);

void dateTimePicker1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 SendKeys.Send("{right}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to customize datetimepicker.create usercontrol with datetimepicker and handle keydown event

Answer (score 0):

A DateTimePicker responds to the right arrow key simply by toggling which of hours and minutes has focus. This means that if the DTP loses focus and then regains it the focus goes back to hours. You can get around this by disposing of the DTP and then re-instantiating it so that the SendKeys.Send("{right}") always starts from the hours having focus but that may present you with the problem of where to do that.

I think that have solved the problem by:

- Set the "ShowUpDown" property of the DTP to false.
- Add a NumericUpDown control to your form
- Make the "Width" of the NUD 18 pixels to hide its value box
- Carefully place the NUD over the DTP's date select down arrow so that it looks a bit like the DTP's Up/Down arrows
- Set the "Maximum" property of the NUD to 1 and the "Minimum" to -1
- Double-click the NUD's "ValueChanged" event to create an event handler and add the following code to make the handler look like this:

```
private bool GfChangeingNudValueByCode = false;

private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!GfChangeingNudValueByCode)
    {
        // Only do this when the user has changed the NUD's value not when this code
        // changes it to zero at the end of this handler
        if (numericUpDown1.Value == -1)
        {
            // The user has pressed the down arrow so decrement the DTP's value
            dateTimePicker1.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddMinutes(-1);
        }

        if (numericUpDown1.Value == 1)
        {
            // The user has pressed the up arrow so increment the DTP's value
            dateTimePicker1.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddMinutes(1);
        }

        // Reset the NUD's value to zero so that we can tell which arrow the user
        // presses next but first set the flag to true otherwise we would get a
        // stack-overflow when we set the NUD's value to zero which results in
        // this event handler being re-entered and re-entered and re-entered ...
        GfChangeingNudValueByCode = true;
        numericUpDown1.Value = 0;
        GfChangeingNudValueByCode = false;
    }
}
```

This results in a DTP/NUD combination which looks like a DTP and the user can change the time value by:

- Typing numbers in the hours or minutes fields
- Pressing the up, down, left and right arrows on the keyboard to change whichever field, hour or minute, has focus
  and best of all
- Clicking the up/down arrows of the NUD which changes the time comprehensively: the hours change when the minutes go from 59 to 0 or from 0 to 59.

QEF